# How to override cloudfront response for a specific path pattern and specific status code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm getting 404 errors on a specific path pattern say xyz/index.html, how to return custom HTML content instead of a 404 Not Found error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using CLoudfront Edge Functions:

- Create lambda function in `us-east-1` region (irrespective of your local region).
- Update the function role `Trusted Relationships` to allow access for cloudfront.

  ```json
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "edgelambda.amazonaws.com",
                    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
  }
  ```
- Update the function code to handle the origin response.

```py
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = event['Records'][0]['cf']['response']

    is_404_page = int(response['status']) == 404
    
    is_html_page =  "index.html" in event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']["uri"]

    if is_404_page and is_html_page:
        response['status'] = 200
        response['statusDescription'] = 'OK'
        response['body'] = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Response</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Custom response page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
    """

    return response
```

- Deploy Function.
- Click on Actions -> Choose Deploy to Lambda@Edge under `Capabilities`
- Configure the CloudFront trigger, and deploy it.
- It takes around 5 minutes to update CloudFront distribution, then you can test your changes.